# SQL query which checks the table and returns yes or no if both values exist in the table

Tags: sql-server

What I want to achieve is that using case statement or anything else I want to query the table and check if in the table we have these values then return 'yes' else 'NO.'

```
SELECT COUNT(Name) 
FROM [dbo].[Notification] 
WHERE Name IN ('Game', 'Gamer')
```

Currently this is returning the count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the `distinct` values of `Name`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Name) = 2 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS result 
FROM [dbo].[Notification] 
WHERE Name IN ('Game', 'Gamer')
```

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Count(*) > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END As status
FROM   dbo.Notification
WHERE  Name IN ('Game', 'Gamer')
;
```

Or the more faster and efficient method would be:

```
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM   dbo.Notification
  WHERE  Name IN ('Game', 'Gamer')
)
  BEGIN
    SELECT 'Yes' AS status;
  END
ELSE 
  BEGIN
    SELECT 'No' AS status;
  END
;
```

Comment: No one will check for both and will return 'Yes' even one value exists and others not.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, it's one way, there's many other ways.  Is this the best way?  Probably not, but it's easy enough to follow:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.[notification] WHERE [name] = 'Game')
            AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.[notification] WHERE [name] = 'Gamer')
        THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
    END;
```